# Display Special character with PHP extracted from database

Tags: php, html

currently in my webpage i am using for this for webpage.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php 
$getDetails = "SELECT details FROM 'school'";
    $linkDetails = mysqli_query($link, $getDetails)or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $displayDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($linkDetails)?>
```

when it display in my webpage it will have ���� replacing a dash or apostrophe.

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: So you want to format special characters in safe way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the below one.?

```
   <?php echo htmlentities($displayDetails); ?>
```